# BASH/shell script, blkid fails with newlines in drive labels

Tags: bash, shell, sed, eval

I have a BASH/shell script, running on Linux, but it sometimes has a problem getting the drive labels, using blkid.. blkid gets the drive labels nad UUIDs of the given drive.

Example of blkid output:

```
# blkid /dev/sda1
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Home" UUID="f1e5e82b-1c75-4fd7-8841-6ad766152dcf" TYPE="ext2"
```

The problem occurs when the drive label has a newline character... I have included the relevant function. The problem seems to be with the eval command.. Can someone help me?

```
blkid_name_generator() {
   #Gather blkid output and filter out required device
   if [ ! -f /tmp/blkid.txt ]; then
      blkid -c /dev/null > /tmp/blkid.txt
   fi
   blkid_cleaner &
   LABEL=""
   LABEL1=""
   eval $( cat /tmp/blkid.txt | grep "$@:" | cut --delimiter=" " -f 2- | sed -e 's/ /;/g')
   LABEL1=${LABEL//;/ } # akita beta4 fix: remove newlines below
   LABEL=`echo $LABEL1 | tr -d '\n'` # akita beta5 fix, remove newlines from drive label
   #Generate drive label
   [ "$LABEL" = "" ] && ONEDRVLABEL="$@\n \n " || ONEDRVLABEL="${LABEL}\n($@)\n "
   echo "${LABEL}" and "${ONEDRVLABEL}"
} 

blkid_name_generator /dev/sda1
```

Comment: what is `blkid_cleaner`? does it modify contents of /tmp/blkid.txt?

Comment: of course the bleedingly obvious fix is to reject bad volume names.

Comment: Yes, tried various ways of ignoring dodgy labels... I get an error from 'eval' every time there is a newline... And I don't know for sure, blkid_cleaner not installed, but the function posted can be used instead to achieve what I want

Comment: try surrounding the cmd that is being evaled with dbl-quotes. Good luck.

Comment: tried that already shellter, but thanks for the idea... I had assumed that would work, to be honest... I have also used 'tr' and 'sed' to no avail - although the usage is correct..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my bash snippet:

```
while read curline; do
  if [[ ${curline:0:1} == "/" ]]; then
    [[ $prevline ]] && echo "$prevline"
    prevline="$curline"
  else
    prevline+="$curline"
  fi
done < $INPUTFILE

[[ $prevline ]] && echo "$prevline"
```

Here's my test file:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Boot" UUID="fdc5e51d-3da6-4edf-bf07-6397b1765797" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Root" UUID="f883df24-1b93-46fb-8990-840774c380c4" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Usr" UUID="ba759de3-e0e4-4603-a324-f11dc25fa784" TYPE="reiserfs"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Persis
tents" UUID="50b81ef0-a38b-4677-b9d9-9548b29ce2bb" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Tempo
raries" UUID="a649c535-1a8a-4b2b-b0a0-4afbdc60a3bc" TYPE="reiserfs"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="Usr
Portage" UUID="a228148e-6405-4bbe-990f-df6eaebb1b1d" TYPE="reiserfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Boot" UUID="fdc5e51d-3da6-4edf-bf07-6397b1765797" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Root" UUID="f883df24-1b93-46fb-8990-840774c380c4" TYPE="ext4"
```

Here's my test file after processed by the bash snippet:

```
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Boot" UUID="fdc5e51d-3da6-4edf-bf07-6397b1765797" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Root" UUID="f883df24-1b93-46fb-8990-840774c380c4" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sda3: LABEL="Usr" UUID="ba759de3-e0e4-4603-a324-f11dc25fa784" TYPE="reiserfs"
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="Persistents" UUID="50b81ef0-a38b-4677-b9d9-9548b29ce2bb" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdc1: LABEL="Temporaries" UUID="a649c535-1a8a-4b2b-b0a0-4afbdc60a3bc" TYPE="reiserfs"
/dev/sdd1: LABEL="UsrPortage" UUID="a228148e-6405-4bbe-990f-df6eaebb1b1d" TYPE="reiserfs"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Boot" UUID="fdc5e51d-3da6-4edf-bf07-6397b1765797" TYPE="ext2"
/dev/sda2: LABEL="Root" UUID="f883df24-1b93-46fb-8990-840774c380c4" TYPE="ext4"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see exactly what your *script* is intending to do (apart from the missing bits).

Here's what I came up with:

```
blkid | perl -ne 'print "$1\n" if m/LABEL="(.*?)"/o'
```

It will show this (on my system):

```
test^J123
WIN7VIRT
TEMP
```

Note how the newline in the label is depicted as `^J` ? Viewing through a hex encoder shows that it is indeed a two-character combination 0x5e 0x4a

Hope you can get some further with that.

---

PS: 'proof' that the newline is in fact correctly in the volume label

```
tune2fs /dev/sdc1 -l
tune2fs 1.41.14 (22-Dec-2010)
Filesystem volume name:   test
123
Last mounted on:          /media/9868d90c-aede-4e7a-b105-d9312f8b17ab
Filesystem UUID:          9868d90c-aede-4e7a-b105-d9312f8b17ab
Filesystem magic number:  0xEF53
Filesystem revision #:    1 (dynamic)
...
```

and on block level:

```
dd if=/dev/sdc1 count=10 | xxd | grep 123
0000470: b105 d931 2f8b 17ab 7465 7374 0a31 3233  ...1/...test.123
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to this question... I could find a solution for another problem. Example (sda2 = ntfs partition):

## blkid /dev/sda2

Segmentation Fault (core dump)

Hard to find troubleshooting guide for this issue (ubuntu based OS or any other)

The reason behind is a malformed LABEL in NTFS partition. 
(of course, mal-formation we cant see, as newlines ;-)
Solution: Clear LABEL with GParted; then rewrite it or set a new LABEL.